# The political parties expressed support to / for the strike

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions, difference

> **The politicians  expressed   their support  to  the  strike / to  the  trade  unions**

The  English  professor  I  know  told  me  that  we  exprees  our  support  for something but  not  express support  to  the  strike  or  to  the  trade  unions.

I  think :

> **The  politicians  extended  their  support  to  the  strike  or  to  the  trade  unions**   is  correct.

We  find  the  expression  **The political  parties  expressed  their  support to  the  strike  or  to  the  trade unions**  in some  English  news  papers  in India.

> **I would  like to  know  whether  both  the  expressions  express support  to/ extend  support  to  the  strike  are  correct or  only  extend  support  to  the  strike  is  correct?**

Comment: Check your question for minor spelling mistakes.  It's *express* not exprees, and *professor* not profeesor.  You may be accidentally doubling the wrong letter  :)

Answer (score 2):

You express support **for** a cause. You can express that support **to** a particular person or group.

> Alice expressed to Bob her support for the new policy.
>
> - Alice expressed her support for the new policy. (To whom Alice expressed her support is not stated.)
> - Alice expressed her support to Bob. (What Alice supports is not stated.)

Alice supports the new policy, and communicated that fact to Bob.

---

To "extend" support has a more narrow usage: it is only appropriate when the subject is taking specific action to directly aid a specific person or group of people. If you "extend your support to the local food kitchen" it means you give them a donation or put in some volunteer hours. If your support is simply ideological, you are not "extending" support.

That said, Indian dialects of English are well-known for using words in ways that speakers of older varieties of English (e.g., American and British English) would find odd, awkward or even incorrect. Such could conceivably be the case here.